# undefined reference to `setup(int, char**)'

Tags: c, cuda, nvcc

I am working on a project to train multi-layer neural networks using CUDA C. The problem is that when I try to complile the program I get this error:

```
facetrain.o: In function `backprop_face':
facetrain.c:(.text+0x127): undefined reference to `bpnn_train_kernel'
backprop_kernel.o: In function `bpnn_train_kernel(BPNN*, float*, float*)':
tmpxft_0002fa78_00000000-4_backprop_kernel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x6e6): undefined reference to `bpnn_layerforward(float*, float*, float**, int, int)'
tmpxft_0002fa78_00000000-4_backprop_kernel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x703): undefined reference to `bpnn_output_error(float*, float*, float*, int, float*)'
tmpxft_0002fa78_00000000-4_backprop_kernel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x72a): undefined reference to `bpnn_hidden_error(float*, int, float*, int, float**, float*, float*)'
tmpxft_0002fa78_00000000-4_backprop_kernel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x745): undefined reference to `bpnn_adjust_weights(float*, int, float*, int, float**, float**)'
backprop_kernel.o: In function `main':
tmpxft_0002fa78_00000000-4_backprop_kernel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x9a5): undefined reference to `setup(int, char**)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [backprop] Error 1
```

Here is the code of backdrop_kernel.cu:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

extern void bpnn_layerforward(float *l1, float *l2, float **conn, int n1, int n2);

extern void bpnn_output_error(float *delta, float *target, float *output, int nj, float *err);

extern void bpnn_hidden_error(float *delta_h, int nh, float *delta_o, int no, float **who, float *hidden, float *err);

extern void bpnn_adjust_weights(float *delta, int ndelta, float *ly, int nly, float **w, float **oldw);


extern int setup(int argc, char** argv);

extern float **alloc_2d_dbl(int m, int n);

extern float squash(float x);

double gettime() {
  struct timeval t;
  gettimeofday(&t,NULL);
  return t.tv_sec+t.tv_usec*1e-6;
}

unsigned int num_threads = 0;
unsigned int num_blocks = 0;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Program main
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int
main( int argc, char** argv) 
{
    setup(argc, argv);
}


void bpnn_train_kernel(BPNN *net, float *eo, float *eh)
{
  int in, hid, out;
  float out_err, hid_err;

  in = net->input_n;
  hid = net->hidden_n;
  out = net->output_n;   

#ifdef GPU  
  int m = 0;
  float *input_hidden_cuda;
  float *input_cuda;
  float *output_hidden_cuda;
  float *partial_sum;
  float *hidden_partial_sum;
  float *hidden_delta_cuda;
  float *input_prev_weights_cuda;
  float sum;
  float *input_weights_one_dim;
  float *input_weights_prev_one_dim;
  num_blocks = in / 16;  
  dim3  grid( 1 , num_blocks);
  dim3  threads(16 , 16);

  input_weights_one_dim = (float *) malloc((in + 1)* (hid + 1) * sizeof(float));
  input_weights_prev_one_dim = (float *) malloc((in + 1)* (hid + 1) * sizeof(float));
  partial_sum = (float *) malloc(num_blocks * WIDTH * sizeof(float));

  // this preprocessing stage is added to correct the bugs of wrong memcopy using two-dimensional net->inputweights
  for (int k = 0; k <= in; k++) {   
   for (int j = 0; j <= hid; j++) {
      input_weights_one_dim[m] = net->input_weights[k][j];
      input_weights_prev_one_dim[m] = net-> input_prev_weights[k][j];
      m++;
    }
  }

  cudaMalloc((void**) &input_cuda, (in + 1) * sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc((void**) &output_hidden_cuda, (hid + 1) * sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc((void**) &input_hidden_cuda, (in + 1) * (hid + 1) * sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc((void**) &hidden_partial_sum, num_blocks * WIDTH * sizeof(float));


#endif

#ifdef CPU

  printf("Performing CPU computation\n");
  bpnn_layerforward(net->input_units, net->hidden_units,net->input_weights, in, hid);

#endif

#ifdef GPU

  printf("Performing GPU computation\n");

  //printf("in= %d, hid = %d, numblocks = %d\n", in, hid, num_blocks);

  cudaMemcpy(input_cuda, net->input_units, (in + 1) * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(input_hidden_cuda, input_weights_one_dim, (in + 1) * (hid + 1) * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);



  bpnn_layerforward_CUDA<<< grid, threads >>>(input_cuda,
                                              output_hidden_cuda,
                                              input_hidden_cuda,
                                              hidden_partial_sum,
                                              in,
                                              hid);

  cudaThreadSynchronize();

  cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("bpnn kernel error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  cudaMemcpy(partial_sum, hidden_partial_sum, num_blocks * WIDTH * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  for (int j = 1; j <= hid; j++) {
    sum = 0.0;
    for (int k = 0; k < num_blocks; k++) {  
      sum += partial_sum[k * hid + j-1] ;
    }
    sum += net->input_weights[0][j];
    net-> hidden_units[j] = float(1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-sum)));
  }
  #endif

  bpnn_layerforward(net->hidden_units, net->output_units, net->hidden_weights, hid, out);
  bpnn_output_error(net->output_delta, net->target, net->output_units, out, &out_err);
  bpnn_hidden_error(net->hidden_delta, hid, net->output_delta, out, net->hidden_weights, net->hidden_units, &hid_err);  
  bpnn_adjust_weights(net->output_delta, out, net->hidden_units, hid, net->hidden_weights, net->hidden_prev_weights);

#ifdef CPU

  bpnn_adjust_weights(net->hidden_delta, hid, net->input_units, in, net->input_weights, net->input_prev_weights);

#endif  


#ifdef GPU

  cudaMalloc((void**) &hidden_delta_cuda, (hid + 1) * sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc((void**) &input_prev_weights_cuda, (in + 1) * (hid + 1) * sizeof(float));

  cudaMemcpy(hidden_delta_cuda, net->hidden_delta, (hid + 1) * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(input_prev_weights_cuda, input_weights_prev_one_dim, (in + 1) * (hid + 1) * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(input_hidden_cuda, input_weights_one_dim, (in + 1) * (hid + 1) * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


  bpnn_adjust_weights_cuda<<< grid, threads >>>(hidden_delta_cuda,  
                                                hid, 
                                                input_cuda, 
                                                in,
                                                input_hidden_cuda, 
                                                input_prev_weights_cuda
                                                );

  cudaMemcpy(net->input_units, input_cuda, (in + 1) * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaMemcpy(input_weights_one_dim, input_hidden_cuda, (in + 1) * (hid + 1) * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  cudaFree(input_cuda);
  cudaFree(output_hidden_cuda);
  cudaFree(input_hidden_cuda);
  cudaFree(hidden_partial_sum);
  cudaFree(input_prev_weights_cuda);
  cudaFree(hidden_delta_cuda);

  free(partial_sum);
  free(input_weights_one_dim);
  free(input_weights_prev_one_dim);

#endif   

}
```

If you need any more info or code let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's a linker error. ld is the linker, so if you get an error message ending with "ld returned 1 exit status", that tells you that it's a linker error.

The error message tells you that none of the object files you're linking against contains a definition for bpnn_layerforward(), bpnn_output_error(),.

The reason for that is that the function you've defined is called bpnn_layerforward(), bpnn_output_error(),.  (in other words: you misspelled the function name when calling the function (and presumably in the header file as well - otherwise you'd have gotten a different error at compile time)).

I think these functions are part of library, you have to include that library when you make executable.

Comment: He might not have misspelt it, it may be a C/C++ name mangling issue, i.e. he forgot the `extern "C" {` that is needed for C++ to skip name mangling. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c